# How to Transfer file from the AS400 system using SFTP

Tags: ssh, sftp, file-transfer

I have a CL program with me which calls the QSH command as below. By executing the command from the program, I am able to establish connectivity with the SFTP server from the AS400 system.

```
**QSH CMD('sftp -i Key_path_file User_ID@Server_IP')**
```

Now I am trying to transfer the file from the AS400 system to the SFTP server. For this, I have a script ready with me.
File transfer is successful while executing the below script using/calling QP2TERM from the AS400 system.

```
**lcd File_Path
put File_name.txt
quit**
```

I am looking for the command which not only establishes the connection but also sends the file from my AS400 system to the SFTP server using the QSH command which will be called by the cl Program.

Comment: No much thing we can do for you on the *niX side. Could retry under SE or retrocomputing SE ?